# What are the physics behind a spin drink cooler?

Tags: temperature, rotation, cooling, liquid-state

I just came across this [spin drink cooler project](http://www.instructables.com/id/Student-Hacks-Chill-Any-Drink-in-60-Seconds-With-O/) on Instructables, that purports to cool a drink in 60 seconds.

You attach the can to some swiftly rotating device, like a drill or a motor, and immerse it in an ice water bath. 60 seconds later, you have an ice cold drink!

I *think* that it makes sense - I've never tried one so I can't vouch for it's efficacy, but I was curious: how does it work?

When I saw the claim it made I immediately thought of the [Hilsch vortex tube](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Hilsch-vortex-tube/) (another project found on Instructables).

Do they use the same principle, or are there two different principles at play here?

Comment: No offence  intended Wayne, but I will just put a quick summary up here to save other users time (and those who don't like movies ). 1.  Get a large bucket of ice.  2.  Take out a can of beer.  3. Attach a handheld device (like a can opener but with a sucker on top) to hold the beer. 4. Put the spinning can into the ice and it cools it down. A claim is made that the spinning makes all the beer cold, fair enough  The video is 5 minutes long, reading this took 1 minute. That's it physicswise.........

Comment: @CountTo10 added some description to my question for the others who have better things to do with their time :)

Comment: I seriously don't mean any offence Wayne, I will delete it if you want, but two things: There is really no physics in putting a can of beer into ice and being surprised when it cools down, some users **will** get annoyed at you and 2. Genuinely, lots (and lots) of users don't like videos that tell them nothing, except the product name.  But say the word and I will delete the comment, no prob.

Comment: I've heard this one before & I thought the Mythbusters covered this one, but alas they [tried other methods](http://mythresults.com/episode29). I'm still not sure I believe rotating could cool it in ~1/5 the time of just sitting in the ice-water.

Comment: @CountTo10 None taken - I didn't think to add a description of the video, but that's totally appropriate. The Instructable actually teaches you how to make your own, vs pay whatever someone is charging (and of course doesn't explain any of the physics that may or may not be at play here, hence my question).